# PayPalAPI EndPoint

Tags: asp.net, paypal

I am using PayPal Express Checkout. After adding the SandBox Service Reference

```
(https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/wsdl/PayPalSvc.wsdl)
```

I got the following endpoint address:

```
https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/
```

However, this link was not running and giving the following error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to api.sandbox.paypal.com.

SSL peer was unable to negotiate an acceptable set of security parameters.

(Error code: ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert)
```

Comment: can you please provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong endpoint.  For SOAP, you'll use the following...

Live Server w/ Signature: https://api-3t.paypal.com/2.0/

Live Server w/ Certificate: https://api.paypal.com/2.0/

Sandbox Server w/ Signature:  https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/

Sandbox Server w/ Certificate: https://api.sandbox.com/2.0/

For more details, see page 18 of the [PayPal SOAP documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_API_Reference.pdf).